# Method to shuffle the members of a class randomly

Tags: java, android, algorithm

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class EnglishWords {

    private final String word1;
    private final String word2;
    private final String word3;
    private final String word4;


    public EnglishWords(String word1Arg, String word2Arg, String word3Arg, String word4Arg) {
        this.word1 = word1Arg;
        this.word2 = word2Arg;
        this.word3 = word3Arg;
        this.word4 = word4Arg; 
    }

    public String getword1() {
        return word1;
    }

    public String getword2() {
        return word2;
    }


        public String getword3(){
            return word3; 
        }

        public String getword4(){
            return word4; 
        }
    }
```

I create an object like this:

```
EnglishWords englishWords = new EnglishWords(words.get(0),
                words.get(1), words.get(2), wordPair.getEnglishWord());
```

Is there some kind of sort method I can add to the class that shuffles the members so they are ordered randomly?

Comment: Not if you declare your fields with `final`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can hold them in a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and use [`Collections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29) to shuffle the list.

If you are eager to shuffle it by your own, or interested how it can be done - [fisher-yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) gives a uniformly distributed permutation of a given list.

Comment: @brux: I am not sure my 2.5 years gf will like it, but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using Math.Random and limit it to the number of words you want to have so that it pseudorandomly picks a word every time it generates a number... Or if you want to set the words in a randomly shuffled way use the same thing before adding them to englishwords!

Edit: what amit said is better, forgot about it totally! :$

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
List<String> argumentList = new ArrayList<String>();

agumentList.add(words.get(0));
agumentList.add(words.get(1));
agumentList.add(words.get(2));
agumentList.add(wordPair.getEnglishWord());

Collections.shuffle(argumentList);

EnglishWords englishWords = new EnglishWords(argumentList.get(0), argumentList.get(1), argumentList.get(2), argumentList.get(3));
```